# Please explain the meaning of FAT 36

Tags: windows-xp

To update the GPS map system in my car the manual states that the USB used to download the updates from the Internet has to be FAT 36.
Please can you tell me what this means?

Comment: Most likely you mean FAT32 or FAT16. It is the filesystem of the USB Stick. Chances are you formatted it to something different. You can reformat it and select the filesystem you need, but keep in mind that will destroy ALL data on the drive you are formatting. Also make very sure you select the correct drive.

Comment: Can you confirm this is FAT 36 and not FAT 32? Sorry didn't see the comment above when I was typing this.... sounds like good advise above!

Comment: Can you take a picture of the manual and upload or link to it

Answer (score 3):

FAT32 or FAT16 (File Allocation Table - 16-bit or 32-bit) is a type of filesystem used by drives to organise the data on the disk.  It is the method by which the drive itself indexes which pieces of memory (storage) are allocated to which files.

There are 2 common types of FAT - FAT16 and FAT32 which contain multiple differences.  These differences are descrivbes very thoroughly in the [FAT Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table).

There are numerous other types of drive formatting - EXFAT, NTFS, EFS... the list goes on and on.

To change the formatting type on your USB, pop it into your computer, open "my computer", righ tclick the USB drive and choose "format".  This will bring up a window with multiple formatting options:
[image: Formatting USB]

**BEWARE** that formatting a USB drive will **DELETE** all data from it.  Be sure to back it up first